# acessing a subnetwork from within a vm

Tags: windows-7, ip, rhel5, vmware-player

I have a pc running windows 7.
I have vmwareplayer running RHEL5
I have 1 physical ethernet connection.
this ethernet connection is wired to a hub.
there is another device on that hub that needs to be in a certain subnetwork (192.168.0.xxx)(lets call him device X)
but the general network is 192.168.1.xxx

How can I configure the network adapters so that I can ping device X from RHEL5 in the vm.

Originally I could ping google from both windows and rhel (I was in the .1 network) but not device X since he is on a different subnetwork address.  Now that I have put it on the .0 I can ping device X from windows but not from rhel5 and cannot access the web. I did this by manually setting the IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question's been asked to death, basically use bridged networking.

Comment: tried that didn't work.

Comment: doesn't mean it's not right though - give us LOTS more detail and then we might be able to add more to our answers.

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work,  thanks for mentionning it had to be bridged even though there were other details involved I ended up being able to get it to work

Comment: No problem, though in future you may find that any questions you have may have been answered on here before, worth searching if you can.